# Redução de código em query sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, query

Eu criei uma **query** com o seguinte objetivo: **Selecionar** todas as **ferramentas** as quais os **estoques** delas **não** estão **presentes** em todas as **empresas**. Uma **Ferramenta** possui um ou mais estoques, um **estoque** pertence a somente uma **empresa**.

Preciso saber se há alguma maneira de fazer essa query para evitar essa redundância de códigos, não sei se estou tendo um dia ruim por isso não consegui fazer melhor mas o que saiu foi isso:

```
select * from ferramenta f
where f.obrigatorio = 1 and (f.codigo not in (select ferramenta_codigo
                                            from estoque
                                            where empresa_codigo = 2)
                         or f.codigo not in (select ferramenta_codigo
                                            from estoque
                                            where empresa_codigo = 3)
                         or f.codigo not in (select ferramenta_codigo
                                            from estoque
                                            where empresa_codigo = 4)
                         or f.codigo not in (select ferramenta_codigo
                                            from estoque
                                            where empresa_codigo = 5)
                         or f.codigo not in (select ferramenta_codigo
                                            from estoque
                                            where empresa_codigo = 6))                                               
order by f.codigo desc
```

> Somente existem as empresas 2,3,4,5,6.

Comment: não vejo necessidade da utilização de todos estes operadores OR. Basta passar a listagem de ID com uma condição IN na consulta da tabela estoque.

Comment: Foram adicionados tags PostgreSQL e oracle, qual efetivamente é o banco usado?

Comment: Se eu adicionar "in" ele vai procurar qualquer um dentro do "in" preciso que traga todos do "in" ou nenhum, resultando nesse codigo que eu fiz. Estou usando postgres

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa utilizar o `or`, basta usar somente a instrução `not in` no campo `empresa_codigo`, desta forma ajuda na performasse da sua `query` e ainda atende o que você pediu, diminuindo no seu tamanho, veja o resultado abaixo:

```
select * from ferramenta f
where f.obrigatorio = 1 
and f.codigo not in (select ferramenta_codigo
                     from estoque
                     where empresa_codigo not in(2,3,4,5,6))                                             
order by f.codigo desc
```

Comment: Nao resolveu, para este exemplo que voce me deu so funcionaria se eu tivesse uma empresa com qualquer numero exceto estes.... O que nao daria certo porque empresa_codigo é FK, como exemplo eu criei uma ferramenta e adicionei ela nas empresas 2,3,4,5 e nao adicionei na 6 e o resultado foi o mesmo de antes...

Answer (score 0):

Talvez desta forma (penso que percebi bem a questão):

```
SELECT      F.* 
FROM        ferramenta  F
LEFT JOIN   estoque     E ON E.ferramenta_codigo = F.codigo
WHERE       F.obrigatorio = 1
        AND (
                    E.empresa_codigo <> 2
                OR  E.empresa_codigo <> 3
                OR  E.empresa_codigo <> 4
                OR  E.empresa_codigo <> 5
                OR  E.empresa_codigo <> 6
            )
ORDER BY    F.codigo DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se o select abaixo atende ao que precisas:

```
select * 
  from ferramenta f 
 where f.obrigatorio = 1 
   and (select count(*) 
          from (select e.empresa_codigo
                  from estoque e
                 where e.empresa_codigo in (2,3,4,5,6)
                   and e.ferramenta_codigo=f.codigo) int
        )<5
```